# Does Samsung process its single take images in China?

Tags: samsung, geotagging

I was in my backyard, taking pictures of the bees on the trees. I got inside and noticed that one of the single take pictures I'd taken on my s10 T-Mobile version had a location tag from Yushu, Qinghai, China. This wasn't an original single take picture, but a screenshot taken from a video. All other files were located in the US. There are some other files that I want to include but are too big, so here's a google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oRtqoJ6z3j4CbI-TN5n1phme2KGKSeYq/view?usp=sharing) to the rest of them.

So, that brings me to the question of whether Samsung sends photos/videos taken on Samsung devices to be processed in China? Is it even possible? Thanks!

[image]
[image: screenshot button]

Comment: You know that the geo location is just some meta data inside the image? It can be set to any place on the world. May be the location you encountered was some default value the Chinese manufacturer had set in production.

Comment: Normally the processing of captured images doesn't take place remotely. It's a built-in feature of camera app. If the camera app is location-aware, it saves the current location of your device in the metadata of the image along with other info like captured date, camera specs, dimensions, resolution etc. So might be your device was reporting wrong location at the moment you captured that image? The same may hold true if that's a screenshot. But I've never seen location being saved in screenshots.

Comment: There is [a similar case on different phones (ZTE) mentioning a bug before the Android Nougat update](https://community.zteusa.com/discussion/16091/pics-show-china-as-location-how-do-i-change-this) and [geotag just gives random locations on other models](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/91925). While this doesn't mean the same issue, it might be a more global issue than a specific model.

Comment: @IrfanLatif The filename and it's path `VideoCapture...` clearly indicates that the image was not taken by what we call "screenshot". Looks more like it was created by some app that is specialized on frame-extraction from videos.

Comment: @Robert correct. I addressed what the OP said.

Comment: OP here. @Robert, it wasn't exactly a screenshot. It was one of Samsung's camera app things. You can see the button I pressed on the right picture.

Comment: Did some more digging... all of the other VideoCapture files on my phone don't have geotags, so this was probably a bug. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to resolve this question, thanks to @Robert and @IrfanLatif in the comments. Did some digging and this is probably just a bug. If it happens again, well, I'll see. Additional thought: Onedrive is connected to the photos app so maybe something with that.